# Is "peckish" less common in American English than other varieties?

Tags: american-english, australian-english

In SuperHolly's video about visiting Australia at around [3:04](https://youtu.be/qZZyyRU4lYI?t=184), Holly mentions coming across the word "peckish" for the first time. As an Australian, I wasn't aware of the word being more common in Australian English than American English.

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peckish) doesn't indicate it's specific to a dialect of English, and according to Google NGrams the word is in the same order of magnitude in [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peckish&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeckish%3B%2Cc0) and [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peckish&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeckish%3B%2Cc0) English (the closest they have to Australian English).

Is the word less common in American English than other varieties of English?

Comment: Note that in the AmE Google Search there are false positives such as: https://books.google.it/books?id=4ocQmzBiBMcC&pg=PA98&dq=%22peckish%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjoz_X0hsfqAhX7ysQBHVkdAFoQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22peckish%22&f=false and https://books.google.it/books?id=j8punfFzSfoC&pg=PA198&dq=%22peckish%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi24rrch8fqAhXXwMQBHXSAAGo4ChDoATADegQIARAT#v=onepage&q=%22peckish%22&f=false

Comment: I agree, I am in the US; it is rare here.  I first heard this term from a Canadian.

Comment: IMHO it's only common in Australian & British English and perhaps in New Zealand. It is not common in American, Canadian, Singaporean, Malaysian & Indian English

Comment: I've read the word in US texts (and probably heard it on TV shows), but usually in the context of Southern/Hillbilly speech.  Whether true or not, the impression I got of it as a youngster was that it was a "rural" term.  I've never heard it used "live".

Comment: @slebetman I'm Canadian, and it's not unusual to hear it used here. I grew up with the word being used by my parents who, perhaps oddly, came from the US. However, they might have picked it up when here.

Comment: "Feeling a bit peckish" is the kind of thing an American says when trying to sound British.

Comment: In my family "I'm feeling peckish" was common. However, it wasn't as common in most of the US where I grew up. I think it is more common in some regions of the us than in others.

Comment: Growing up in the USA, I knew what "peckish" meant, but mostly from watching movies and TV made in England, or reading books from there. I have never heard it used colloquially by another US national, and it would mostly be used, if at all, the way @barbecue suggests: to imitate a British person.

Comment: Peckish is a phrase that is both generationally and regionally dependent. It is a phrase that is very, very common amongst my older family members and friends from the American South. My younger friends and family members know what the phrase means. But, they do not often use it.

Comment: @GEdgar . I'm 68 and Canadian and I've never heard it. I suspect that most Canadians don't know it at all and would likely guess that it means libidinous.

Comment: Monty Python's "Cheese Shop" sketch was the first time I heard "peckish" used. I don't think I've ever heard the word used in casual speech. (US Midwest, since 80's)

Comment: The only person I've heard use the term in the US is my mom, born in Grimsby in '26.

Comment: @notovny Monty Python was, and remains, the only place where I've heard this word. AmE speaker here, and I have a few British friends.

Comment: As a US American, I used the word "peckish" and was rewarded with two full minutes of laughter from my 18YO daughter, who informed me I was the first person to use that term in about 100 years.  We were treated to hear it twice on television that same day.  :-)

Comment: Didn't [Heckle and Jeckle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heckle_and_Jeckle) say things like "I must say, I'm feeling rather peckish" as a regular justification for stealing food?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, the informal expression peckish, meaning hungry, appears to be mainly used in BrE and AuE:

According to GDoS the term peckish dates back to the 18th century and the usage examples they provide are mainly from AuE and BrE. Peckish derives from
***peck***, (16th C.)
to eat (of a bird).

***[peckish](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/qq3p4ha): (also pecky)*** hungry:

> 1965  [UK]    E. Bond Saved Scene ii: Still pecky? [...] There’s a bit’a choclit left. ’Ere.

> 1971  [UK]    N. Armfelt Catching Up 204: I’m peckish myself.

> 1985  [Aus]   R.G. Barrett You Wouldn’t Be Dead for Quids (1989) 47: Feeling a bit peckish now he [...] threw a T-bone [...] under the griller.

> 1989  [UK]    (con. 1950s–60s) in G. Tremlett Little Legs 29: You come back a bit peckish.

> 1998  [Aus]   R.G. Barrett Mud Crab Boogie (2013) [ebook] ‘Why don’t we order some food [...] I’m feeling a bit peckish’.

> 1999  [UK]    (con. 1979–80) A. Wheatle Brixton Rock (2004) 27: I was feeling a bit peckish, so I thought I’d start dinner early.

> 2001  [UK]    M. Coles Bible in Cockney 70: Did you never read about David when he was peckish and needed something to eat?

The term is mainly BrE according  to the ***American Heritage Dictionary***:

[Peckish:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/peckish)

> 2. (Chiefly British) Somewhat hungry.

and on the usage of peckish [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/peckish) notes that:

> ***While the informal word peckish is more common in the UK, most people in North America will know what you mean if you say, "I'm feeling a little peckish— should we make some popcorn?"*** Some people wake up in the morning feeling peckish, while others don't feel like eating for a few hours.

Comment: Huh. I'm a North American and I didn't know it meant hungry. I assumed it meant "irritable", from context (snooty British television characters complaining how peckish they are).

Answer (score 8):

> According to Google NGrams the word is in the same order of magnitude in American and British English.

Actually, that's not true. Google Books Ngram Viewer does not show that they get the same amount of use.

A query that separates the US corpus from the UK corpus [shows that](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peckish%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cpeckish%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeckish%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeckish%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpeckish%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpeckish%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) *peckish* is almost twice as common in print in the UK as it is in the US:

[image: US peckish versus UK peckish]

Comment: Being in the same order of magnitude means that one case is not _vastly_ different than the other case. It need not be _similar_ magnitude. Specifically it means that one case is not 10x greater than the other case. Like the populations of the USA and China are in the same order of magnitude (though barely). I suspect Wikipedia explains it better than I do.

Comment: @piojo - Outside of rigid statistics, "order of magnitude" is a fairly vague and ill-defined term.

Comment: @piojo Doesn't look like Jason Bafford said they were vastly different

Comment: Just to note, a word showing up less in print doesn't necessarily mean it is used less, only that it is used less *in print*. (Oh wait, sorry, I thought I was on the math stack exchange... :-D )

Comment: At risk of pedantry, "order of magnitude" applies to the sciences in general, not just stats. In fact, in stats, I am usually on the natural log scale, not the common (base 10) log. Speaking of math, order of magnitude refers to the common log scale by convention. But conventions can change, and the relative frequency is about one order of 'magnitude' on a log base 2 scale. That said, I agree that Jason's use is not technically correct (by the current convention). I would probably have said "twice as commonly used" or something similar.

Comment: @WeiwenNg The question specifically asked for a comparison between regions. Although it used *order of magnitude*, that was the incorrect phrase to use with respect to a *comparative* analysis between specific things only. It didn't ask if the word was common *in general* (in which case the answer could be that it's not very common in any or either region; it asked only a comparison where a simple number or percentage to represent that difference is appropriate.

Comment: I would venture to say (with nothing concrete _at all_ to back my statement) that the rise of the use of "peckish" in the US since 1990 (or so) is due in large part to the increase of British TV being shown in the US since then.

Comment: @FreeMan Except that the use of *peckish* ***also*** increased in the UK at that time. Perhaps television contributed to both the US and the UK use, but I would assume that British television would be seen more often in the UK than the US, so if TV were a contributing factor, I'd expect the UK graph to rise more sharply than the US graph. (Actually it seems does seem to. UK use went up twice as much as US use after about 2000. But 2000 is an odd year for it to have been related to TV.)

Comment: @JasonBassford with the internet starting to _really_ take off around 2000, it's not _that_ surprising. More TV use in the UK increases the use there, more international contact due to the internet leads to increased use in the US. As I said, nothing at all concrete to back this up, just speculation.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, the internet is a good source of information for the increase around that time. I'd be interested in seeing if the use the use most words—or most uncommonly used words—also followed the same trend.

Comment: `[Wallace removes the cover from the cheese dish, finds nothing but crumbs]` "Feeling a bit peckish, are we?" --Wallace and Gromit _The Wrong Trousers_ 1993.  <--wild speculation...

Answer (score 5):

I find similar magnitudes to Jason Bafford's [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/540520/130346):

- [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/): *peckish* returns **76 / 1 billion** words.
- [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/): *peckish* returns 27 / 100 million is about **270 / 1 billion words.**

Therefore, *peckish* is approximately 3.6x as common in *written* BrE than general AmE (the corpora draw from different sources).

Answer (score 5):

GloWbE shows it more common in UK websites than in the next three regions put together (which are Ireland, Australia, and Hong Kong).

[image]

Comment: Could that be because GB has a bigger population, akin to https://xkcd.com/1138/ ? Also, those other three countries use English that is more similar to GB than the US.

Comment: Confirming once again, @AndrewGrimm, that there's an XKCD relevant to _everything_.

Answer (score 1):

Canadian here. I've heard it commonly where I live (western Canada, Alberta ). Maybe it's the British influence here, after all, we are technically part of the Commonwealth. Might be regionally dependent in Canada, can't speak for the eastern provinces though.